# How to redefine a class in c#

Tags: c#

In VS, I have referenced a DLL of a library.

I would like to use my own definition of a class that the library/api uses instead of the library's. I want to do this to add functionality to existing classes.

Class extensions do not suffice because I want to add new static methods to classes.

I have the source of the classes I want to reimplement.

Is there a way to redefine the class in my project and use it instead of the dll's class without importing the entire source of the library/dll. I'd rather not import the entire source, just the classes I want to modify.

In fact, the classes I want to modify are not classes but structs, and do not have the partial modifier.

Comment: No.  You can create your own version of the DLL.  But you probably shouldn't do this at all.

Comment: Well, if you have the source code, just add it to your project, no?

Comment: @OldProgrammer I'd rather not import the entire source, just the classes I want to modify, if possible.

Comment: In this case, I'd be inclined to use the most important question in a developer's arsenal: Why do you ask? I can almost guarantee if you want to do this, there's probably something wrong with your design, and a better way of achieving your goal.

Comment: @Flynn1179 I want to add new static methods to a struct definition, in essence.

Comment: Yeah, we got that, but.. why? Where's the perceived benefit in doing this over simply using static methods on a new class, or extension methods?

Comment: @Flynn1179 cleaner looking

Comment: @Blazart: no, what you are proposing does not sound cleaner looking at all. What you need is exactly why extension methods were created. Use them, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try extension methods:

```
namespace DLLNamespace
{
    public struct TestStruct
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public void SetName(string name) { this.Name = name; }
    }
}

namespace ProgramNamespace
{
    public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static void ReverseName(this DLLNamespace.TestStruct target)
        {
            target.Name = new string(target.Name.ToArray().Reverse().ToArray());
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DLLNamespace.TestStruct ts;
            ts.SetName("John");
            ts.ReverseName();
            Console.WriteLine(ts.Name);
        }
    }
}
```